# Avoid recompilation of numba code when using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, numba

I've been using numba for doing multiprocessing.

The only problem - numba recompiles the code for every process separately.

(Its not much of a problem when the number of processes are equal to the number of physical CPUs,
but a huge one when that is not the case!)

Is there any way to make numba compile code once,
and then share the compiled artifacts across process boundaries?

Example -

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import time, sleep
from numba import njit


@njit
def child():
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ps = [Process(target=child) for _ in range(100)]
    for p in ps:
        p.start()
    s = time()
    for p in ps:
        p.join()
    print("compile time:", time() - s)
```

```
compile time: 19.10037922859192
```

CPU usage pegged @ 100% on all cores.
I've tried numba's cache=True, but my code is unfortunately uncachable.

```
/Users/dev/PycharmProjects/trading/tradingdo/strategy.py:91: NumbaWarning: Cannot cache compiled function "_strategy1" as it uses dynamic globals (such as ctypes pointers and large global arrays)
  @njit
```

Comment: multiprocessing cannot share any memory across processes, so unless you can pickle your function somehow, it's probably not possible. Maybe you have to try Cython

Comment: Thanks, I have tried Cython and it is actually slower for my specific application! (Even after annotating all types and ensuring minimal python interfacing via their slick HTML isnpector).

Comment: As for pickling, can numba's cache actually be pickled? Also, is there a way to access the cache in my code in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On systems with `fork()` support (Linux), this is easy -

Simply compile the function once, before starting the processes - this will make numba cache the compiler output, as it does normally.

But because of fork's copy-on-write magic, that cache automatically gets shared with child processes!

What's not so clear is how to do it on systems without proper `fork()` support. Can numba's cache be pickled?

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import time, sleep
from numba import njit


@njit
def child():
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    child() # this will do it

    ps = [Process(target=child) for _ in range(100)]
    for p in ps:
        p.start()
    s = time()
    for p in ps:
        p.join()
    print("compile time:", time() - s)
```

```
compile time: 0.011722326278686523
```

Its also worth looking at numba's [nogil](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html#nogil). This can eliminate the need for Processes, and threads share numba compilation cache just fine

Comment: Threads always make things simpler but they don't give you the same speed up if your child method is cpu intensive.

Comment: `nogil` lets you exploit multiple cores, alleviating this restriction on threads put by python

Comment: awesome - nice tip!

Comment: I think this only works if the jit'ed function is in the same file as in your example. I fail to succeed with this trick when functions that are jit'ed are buried way down in imported classes.